# uninstalling CKeditor 5 from Laravel 6

Tags: ckeditor, uninstallation, laravel-6

I installed CKeditor 5 in laravel 6 by this command:

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

how could I uninstall this package from laravel?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by this command:

```
npm uninstall --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```